# how to make log4j to write to the console as well

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

Is there any way to tell to log4j to write its log to the file and to the console?
thanks
there are my properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,R
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=512KB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

Comment: what does R mean?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Your root logger definition is a bit confused.
See the [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html).

This is a standard Java properties file, which means that lines are treated as key=value pairs.  Your second `log4j.rootLogger` line is overwriting the first, which explains why you aren't seeing anything on the `console` appender.

You need to merge your two `rootLogger` definitions into one.  It looks like you're trying to have `DEBUG` messages go to the console and `INFO` messages to the file.  The root logger can only have *one* level, so you need to change your configuration so that the appenders have appropriate levels.

While I haven't verified that this is correct, I'd guess it'll look something like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

Note that you also have an error in casing - you have console lowercase in one place and in CAPS in another.

Comment: How is the distinction made between DEBUG and INFO? -- as you pointed out yourself that that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: does it work in log4j2?

Answer (score 42):

### Your log4j File should look something like below read comments.

```
# Define the types of logger and level of logging    
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG,console, FILE

# Define the File appender    
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender    

# Define Console Appender    
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender    

# Define the layout for console appender. If you do not 
# define it, you will get an error    
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Set the name of the file    
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)    
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode    
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite    
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender    
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout    
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Answer (score 7):

This works well for console in debug mode

```
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

Comment: does it work in log4j2?

Answer (score 0):

Write the root logger as below for logging on both console and FILE

log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,console,FILE

And write the respective definitions like Target, Layout, and ConversionPattern (MaxFileSize for file etc).

Answer (score 0):

Thats the exact usecase I was looking for my command line based tool. Wanted to show INFO on console but wanted to log more detailed info to log file. After various suggestion, finally go this solved by using 'log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold'
Something like below.:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE,FILE
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=output/log.log
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=DEBUG
```