# Need to display output though return statement instead of system.out.print statement

Tags: java, java-8

Below Code works fine. I get a list of elements printed . But I don't want to use `System.out.println(element);` instead I need `return element;` to print all data. How can I do this?

```
public String getelement() {

     final int size1 = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().size();

     for (int i = 0; i <= size1; i++) {
     final String element = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().get(i).getLongName();
     System.out.println(element);
     }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list or Array and return.

```
    public List<String> getelement() {
        List<String> elementList = new ArrayList<>();
        final int size1 = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().size();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size1; i++) {
            final String element = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().get(i).getLongName();
            elementList.add(element);
        }
       return elementList;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Loggers if you want to do it a clean way. Use log4j >2.5 version to achieve what you are doing. Your code will become the following

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

public String getelement() {

     final int size1 = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().size();

     for (int i = 0; i <= size1; i++) {
     final String element = Export.getdetails().getdata().getdata().get(i).getLongName();
     System.out.println(element);
     }

    return log.traceExit(/*object that you are returning*/);
}
```

See the logger API [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html)

See how you can configure logger to print into a console here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3383006/258741